# Value change for Ng Date Time Picker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, input, datetimepicker, onchange

Nothing of events are not working for ng-pick-datetime

```
<label class="fieldlabel">{{ attribute.attribute.displayName }}: </label>
<label>
  <mat-form-field class="field-full-width">
    <input [owlDateTimeTrigger]="datePicker" placeholder="Date" [owlDateTime]="datePicker"
  [dateTimeInput]="emitValue()" [(ngModel)]="value.value">
    <owl-date-time #datePicker></owl-date-time>
 </mat-form-field>
</label>
```

Also I import needed modules:

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime
[image]

I have the same errors for other events: `afterPickerOpen`,
`yearSelected`, `monthSelected`, `dateTimeChange`

Comment: Did you add the imported modules to the `imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule ]` in your AppModule?

Comment: Yes, sure
        @NgModule({    
             OwlDateTimeModule,
             OwlNativeDateTimeModule })

Comment: Can you put your component in a https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: What is the version of your Angular?

Comment: If I'm not making any mistake then, that should be `@NgModule(imports: [
     OwlDateTimeModule,
        OwlNativeDateTimeModule
    ])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dateTimeInput` is an output (event) not an input. Hence, you need to use `()` instead of `[]`.

```
(dateTimeInput)="emitValue()"
```

For further information on outputs, read the official [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).